# поиск без использования латинских букв wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Возможно ли и как можно сделать так что бы поиск находил результаты со словами в которых есть латинские буквы такие как на пример čėšū, но при том что в поле поиска человек не обязательно бы их использовал? То есть на пример есть пост в котором есть искомое слово "maša", но в данный момент этот пост у меня находит только если я напишу "maša", а я хочу что бы находило и при поиске "masa". В общем буквы čėšū воспринимались как cesu.

Comment: Используйте в поиске транслитерацию.

Comment: Я не смог добиться, чтобы WP НЕ находил слова с диакритикой: http://take.ms/jQWz4

Comment: если ипользовать стандартный шаблон поиска без дополнительный параметров. тогда действительно ищет и находит так как я хочу. но если я использую 's' => $_GET['s'], то тогда не находит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, дело в `COLLATE` таблиц БД. Есть такой рецепт. Попробуйте 
вставить код ниже в functions.php. Он фильтрует запрос поиска по постам и добавляет `COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`.

```
add_filter('posts_search_orderby', 'alter_query', 20, 2);
function alter_query($orderby, $query) {
  return $orderby . ' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci';
}
```

Comment: с этим кодом вообще ничего не находит :(

Comment: а в БД какой collate указан?

Comment: если ипользовать стандартный шаблон поиска без дополнительный параметров. тогда действительно ищет и находит так как я хочу. но если я использую 's' => $_GET['s'], то тогда не находит.

Comment: а этого в постановке вопроса не было )))

Comment: Это вы меня натолкнули на мысль когда сказали что у вас работает. Тогда я закинул стандартный файлик и действительно стало находить. Но мне стандартного не хватает. обязательно надо доп параметры передать :( utf8mb4_unicode_ci